# What is number of possibilities of cases in Inheritance can occur while distributing inheritance according to the Quran?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, inheritance

Many books have been written on Islamic rules of inheritance. I am curious to know   what could be number of possibilities of cases in inheritance distribution

Comment: Please use relevant tags!!! (edited)

Comment: which tag should I use then,I mean why no one wants to answer a question on a question & answer forum I am not asking an out of the topic question @medilsaif

Comment: See the edit history and you will see what I was referring to. We answer questions based on our limited knowledge you must wait until some knowledgeable people find time to answer even on fatwa sites you may need to wait for months. Patience is the key! Maybe [Is the fact that a woman inherits only half the share of a man a kind of injustice?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37419/is-the-fact-that-a-woman-inherits-only-half-the-share-of-a-man-a-kind-of-injusti) is of help.