# Rights and duties of wife when husband is abroad without her consent

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, husband-wife

Assalamoaliqum, I am a working women, mother of one married for more than an year.

At the time of proposal or nikkah it was not mentioned that my husband and I will have to live seperatly and he will visit me once in two years for 10 days if he want to. In the meantime I have to take care of my husbands family speacially mother and father. I was informed about this on my wedding night and choice of divorce was given to me if I dont agree to the above mentioned terms.
It is more than a year now and my husband have not spent anything on me other than two dresses and feeding me  and my son well during our 45 days stay in U.A.E. and paying hospital dues at the time of delivery in his absence. In the mean time I bear expenses of groceries for my home, clothes and shoes and other needs for all four of us (my parents in laws me and my son). Expenses and growing and it is getting hard for me to bear all these expenses. I have asked my husband to share the burden with me but he has gone kind of angry over this. I was upset as well so I argued over the duty of a husband to fulfill the nedds of wife even if she is a billionaire. He said I am a materialistic women and such women will not even smell jannah.

I dont want to spend on the household and want to buy a car to make traveling easy, I dont want to live with my inlaws and wish to live with my husband and leave this job I am doing which my husband wants me to continue, is it wrong? Am I sinnig by doing this? What islam says about this?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to make yourself familiar with our site and model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your question: it is the obligation of a husband to be in charge of his family, it is yours to obey him according to shari'a some madhhabs consider the husband not being in charge for his wife and kid a reason for faskh/invalidation of marriage. See [What does obey mean in 4:34](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31474/what-does-obey-mean-in-righteous-women-are-devoutly-obedient-in-quran-434)

Comment: Relevant Fatwa: http://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=8320

Comment: What you're describing sounds like temporary marriage (نكاح المتعة). You have an undeniable right for your husband to live with you most of the time. You have the right to be supported and you have no obligation to be working to support yourself as long as you're married.